# Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'

Tags: typescript

I am wondering what the correct way is to type this? I have tried quite a few ideas and can't make it happy.

I have tried <T extends object> (same error)

I also tried setting field: keyof T (which gives the error "Type '{ invalid: boolean; valid: boolean; feedback: null; }' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]"

writable is a svelte store.

```js
export function createValidator<T extends Record<string, object>>(formState: T) {
  const vState = {...formState};

  const { subscribe, set, update } = writable<T>(vState);

  async function validate(field: string): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      await validateOrReject(formState);
        
      if(field) {
        update(state => {
          state[field] = { //Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T
            invalid: false,
            valid: true,
            feedback: null
          };

          return state;
        });
      }

.........
```

Comment: why not accept a `Record` directly in the parameter? there's no need for generics here

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mLlGKm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @DanielA.White that worked, but I don't understand why. If you convert your comment to an answer I'll accept it and try to figure it out.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering the same thing. Made a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAMTnAPAFUQUwB5Q5gAmAzogEo4RwBOx6pUtMYA5gDSJwBGAVtSgA+IQApWABxBQAXIkxcA1jgCecpi3YBKOdgDeAKETHEAGxxREwNIgC8iSdIDcBoyetwA2spUBdO4h6iDymAIYAFnIA5CERUYgAvi5uxrQWILRIHi4JrqCQsAiIAEKhtOJgUrKU1HQMGqyc3PyCQkqq6syNOjU09Ixd7Fy8AtBCgSlmFlY29o5QySYzXj7+9oHBYZGIMVvxSa5LaVAZWWg5BkA) and still can't understand why `Bar` compiles and `Foo` does not. Doesn't `T extends sometype` mean that `T` _is_ a `sometype`?

Comment: @tromgy yes, great example. That is exactly why I was confused. It seems they should do the same thing.